# Get element sibling component ng-content from template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to make a popover with angular. Which currently has two components and one directive.

When I click on my button, I get an error saying

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'openPopover' of undefined

How can I get a reference to the parent from the directive and then get the child from that parent?

So, the click path would look like so: `[open-popover] / <map-popover> / <map-popover-content>`

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-popover>
  <mat-popover-content>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </mat-popover-content>
  <button mat-flat-button open-popover color="primary">Add Debt</button>
</mat-popover>
```

**popover.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mat-popover',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
  styleUrls: ['./popover.component.scss']
})
export class MatPopoverComponent {

  @ViewChild(MatPopoverContentComponent)
  public content: MatPopoverContentComponent

  public open() {
    this.content.openPopover()
  }
}
```

**content.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mat-popover-content',
  template: `<ng-template #popoverContent>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ng-template>`,
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.scss']
})
export class MatPopoverContentComponent {

  @ViewChild('popoverContent')
  public template: TemplateRef<any>

  public constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openPopover(): void {
    this.dialog.open(this.template, {
      hasBackdrop: false
    })
  }
}
```

**open.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[open-popover]'
})
export class OpenPopoverDirective {

  public constructor(@Host() private popover: MatPopoverComponent) { }

  @HostListener('click')
  public onClick() {
    this.popover.open()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `ContentChild` decorator with `ViewChild` here `@ViewChild(MatPopoverContentComponent)` and it should work.

### Explanation

You should distinguish Light DOM and Shadow DOM:

**component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mat-popover',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`, <--- Shadow DOM
  styleUrls: ['./popover.component.scss']
})
export class MatPopoverComponent {}
```

**consumer**

```
<mat-popover>
  <!-- Light DOM starts -->
  <mat-popover-content>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </mat-popover-content>
  <button mat-flat-button open-popover color="primary">Add Debt</button>
  <!-- Light DOM ends-->
</mat-popover>
```

So in Angular we query elements in **Shadow DOM by using ViewChild/ren and elements in Light DOM by using ContentChild/ren**